# What is the data flow if using an HSM with an encrypted Database

Tags: database, encryption

How would someone implement an HSM if they wanted to encrypt all the tables of a database for example in a 3-tier environment?

Does the app server query the DB, get the encrypted blob and ask the hsm to decrypt it? That seems like a lot of data for the HSM to pass back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

Why not encrypt the data in front of the database in a proxy,  then have the proxy engage the HSM which is managing the root key?    This way the proxy can be used for other purposes as well.